# IMFMediaEngine and an array of bytes

Tags: audio, windows-runtime, ms-media-foundation

I've a large pack file which contains multiple media assets (there's 5 mp3s in one file). I'm reading the pack file and retrieving an array of bytes (and size of the array). How can I forward this information to `IMFMediaEngine` for it to play it?

Currently I'm creating a `IRandomAccessStream` from a unpacked file and transforming it to `IMFByteStream` by `MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStreamEx` and then sending it to `SetSourceFromByteStream`.

I'd rather just use `byte* data` and `size_t size` to feed the media object. Is it possible?

Comment: I tried change the position of `IMFByteStream` before (and after) sending it to `SetSourceFromByteStream`, but `MediaEngine` insists on always beginning from position 0.